# TypeError 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, sum, integer

```
def summation(n):
    if n>=1:
        return sum((np.arange(1,n+1))**3 + 3(np.arange(1,n+1)**2))
```

```
summation(1)
```

Why is this code returning this type error? Does it have something to do with the sum function?

Comment: Your missing an operator after the `3`: `3(np.arange(1,n+1)**2))`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to multiply incorrectly.

change: `3(np.arange(1,n+1)**2))`

to: `3 * (np.arange(1,n+1)**2))`

You must have the operator when doing arithmetic in code